# Change the type setting of sympy output functions that contain the Heaviside step function from Theta(t) to u(t)

Tags: python, sympy, display, equation

When running Jupyter notebooks, or co-lab notebooks, and a function is returned that includes a step function, it displays the step function as Theta(t) and not u(t).  While Theta(t) is common, when teaching step function concepts to students who are new to the field, switching symbols can cause a bit of unnecessary cognitive load.

Can one change the typesetting from Theta(t) to u(t)?

I tried as many searches of title variations as possible, from the specific change of typesetting to generic, and I can't find any resources on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you modify a `LatexPrinter` to achieve your objective.

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter

class MyLatexPrinter(LatexPrinter):
    def _print_Heaviside(self, expr, exp=None):
        pargs = ', '.join(self._print(arg) for arg in expr.pargs)
        tex = r"u\left(%s\right)" % pargs
        if exp:
            tex = r"\left(%s\right)^{%s}" % (tex, exp)
        return tex

def my_latex(expr, **settings):
    return MyLatexPrinter(settings).doprint(expr)

init_printing(latex_printer=my_latex)
```

With this edit, you can use your expression to achieve other goals, for example plotting:

```py
var("s, t")
expr = 400 / (s**2 + 12*s + 400)
inv_lap = inverse_laplace_transform(expr, s, t)
display(inv_lap)
plot(inv_lap, (t, 0, 2))
```

[image]
[image]

This works because `inv_lap` contains an Heaviside function, which can be evaluated.

Comment: This worked great.  I would upvote it, but I do not have a reputation  yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the printer or, if this is just for display purpose, you can make a custom function that replaces the `Heaviside` with a function `u`:

```py
>>> from sympy import Heaviside, Function
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> Heaviside(x).replace(lambda x: isinstance(x, Heaviside),
...                      lambda x: Function('u')(x.args[0]))
u(x)
```

The 2nd arg of Heaviside determines the value at 0; the replacement just ignores that arg for simplicity; else use `(*x.args)`

Comment: Can you also include the printer modification approach?

Comment: The proposed code works, but I would also like to modify the printer.  This spot looks a good place to start, unless anyone has a better site for examples:https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html